# Next 13 Typescript Fetch API

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch-api

I'm a beginner to Next, I don't know what I did wrong here:

*app.tsx:*

```
import { getCoverage } from "./api/(landing-page)/api";

function PageHome({ coverageData }: { coverageData: any }) {
  console.log(coverageData);

  return (
    // components here
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  let coverageData = null;

  try {
    coverageData = await getCoverage();

    if (!coverageData) {
      throw new Error("Empty or undefined response from the API");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "Error fetching coverage data during server-side rendering:",
      error
    );
  }

  return {
    props: {
      coverageData,
    },
  };
}

export default PageHome;
```

*api.ts:*

```
export async function getCoverage() {
  const res = await fetch("api-endpoint");
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}
```

The `coverageData` props always returned 'undefined', even when I change the API handler and the `getstaticprops`, I tried changing the code to client to no avail.

Comment: Are you using the latest app router?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar yes